# Finding the Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with more that 5 columns where cell values are TRUE or FALSE.

If the cell value in every column is TRUE then in 6th column cell enter "No change".

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | NO Change |

If any cell in these 5 columns has value FALSE need to know which column (2nd or 3rd or 5th).

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | Change in 2nd |

OR

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | Change in 2 and 4 |

```vb
Sub Checking()
    Dim i as Integer
    For i=2 to $lastrow
        If (cell(i,1).value = cell(i,2).value = cell(i,3).value = cell(i,4).value = cell(i,5).value = "TRUE") Then 
           cell(i,"6").value = "No Change"
        Else 
            If (cell(i,1).value = "FALSE") Then
             cell(i,6).value = "1 Changed"
            End If
            If (cell(i,2).value = "FALSE") Then
             cell(i,6).value = "2 Changed"
            End If
            If (cell(i,3).value = "FALSE") Then
             cell(i,6).value = "3 changed"
            End If
            If (cell(i,4).value = "FALSE") Then
             cell(i,6).value = "4 Changed"
            End If
            If (cell(i,5).value = "FALSE") Then
             cell(i,6).value = "5 Changed"
            End If
       Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes this is possible but we are not a code writing service so show us your code and tell us your problem with it.

Comment: Have updated! @RaymondWu! Pls check

Comment: @ConanEdugawa Perhaps you like to explain how is your code not working? Your code as it is can't even compile (`$lastrow` is an invalid variable name.. it's `Cells(x,y)`.. not `Cell(x,y)`)

Comment: Also, `Next i`, not `Next Cell`

Answer (score 1):

1. It's faster to process values in an array than accessing the cells 1 by 1
2. You should declare any variable used to store row number as `Long`. the maximum number of rows in a worksheet is much higher than what `Integer` data type can hold and can potentially cause overflow error. In general you also have no reason to use `Integer` data type in these days so just declare as `Long`.
3. It is good practice to declare all your variables, insert `Option Explicit` at the top of your module to help you enforce this.

Your code can not even compile due to various reasons so below code is not modified from your code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Checking()
    Const firstRow As Long = 2
    Const firstColumn As Long = 1
    Const numToCompare As Long = 5
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change name accordingly
    
    '== Find the last row
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, firstColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    
    '== Get the input values into an array to process faster vs accessing the cells 1 by 1
    Dim inputArr As Variant
    inputArr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(firstRow, firstColumn), ws.Cells(lastRow, firstColumn)).Resize(, numToCompare).Value
    
    Dim outputArr() As String
    ReDim outputArr(1 To UBound(inputArr, 1), 1 To 1) As String
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim falseDict As Object
    
    '== Loop through the array row by row..
    For i = 1 To UBound(inputArr, 1)
        Set falseDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        
        '== For each row, loop through each column to look for False value, add the column number to the dictionary if found
        Dim n As Long
        For n = 1 To UBound(inputArr, 2)
            If inputArr(i, n) = False Then falseDict(firstColumn + n - 1) = 1
        Next n
        
        'Determine the result string
        Dim output As String
        Select Case falseDict.Count
            Case 0: output = "No Change"
            Case Else
                Dim dictKeys As Variant
                dictKeys = falseDict.Keys
                output = "Change in " & Join(dictKeys, ", ")
        End Select
        
        outputArr(i, 1) = output
    Next i
    Set falseDict = Nothing
    
    'Output 1 column after the last column to compare
    Dim outputColumn As Long
    outputColumn = firstColumn + numToCompare
        
    ws.Cells(firstRow, outputColumn).Resize(UBound(outputArr, 1)).Value = outputArr
End Sub
```

Comment: Instructive & helpful +:) Possibly the assumed beginner Conan would need some further explanations of a dictionary. - Fyi Posted an alternative approach using formula evaluation plus filtering @RaymondWu

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative via Evaluation**

Assuming the cell values in cell range `A2:E2`, I demonstrate an approach how one can use the results of a [**formula evaluation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.evaluate) *(getting an array of column numbers explicitly for the cells with value `False`)* and [**join**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function) these elements to the wanted output string.

The *logic* behind the formula `"=Not(A2:E2)*Column(A2:E2)"` can be described as follows:

- `A2:E2` ...................... get the boolean values (true=1|false=0) as they appear in indicated cells
- `Not(A2:E2)` ........... replace(each value by its opposite value: False ~> True=1, True ~> False=0)
- `*Column(A2:E2)`... multiply with the cells' column number, thus receiving values greater than 0 (i.e. the respective column number as result of a multiplication with factor 1) only for the cells with an original `False` entry.

The eventual [**filtering**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filter-function) allows to get the wanted column numbers exclusively, i.e. without zero values. [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function) combines the found elements to a resulting output string, which finally can be written to the 6th column (section c).

```
Option Explicit                          ' Force declaration of variables (head of code module)

Sub DetectFalseValues()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1                      ' << change to required sheet Code(Name)
'a) get column numbers if original cell value equals False (negated as Not True);
'   (vice versa get zero for original True value after negation) 
    Dim allValues() As Variant
    allValues = ws.Evaluate("Not(A2:E2)*Column(A2:E2)")
'b) filter out all zero values and combine elements to string
    Dim output As String
    output = Join(Filter(allValues, 0, False), " and ")
    output = IIf(Len(output) = 0, "No Change", "Change in " & output)
'c) write to target
    ws.Range("F2").Value = output
    ''optional display in VB Editor's immediate window
    ' Debug.Print output                    ' e.g. "Change in 2 and 4"
End Sub
```